# Subactivity onClick Firing in Parent Class

Tags: android, android-intent, onclick, subactivity

I am having some trouble with the onClick handler in a sub activity of an ActivityGroup.

I am launching a StoreActivity using:

```
Intent storeIntent = new Intent(this, StoreActivity.class);
storeIntent.putExtra(StoreActivity.INTENT_STORE_ID, storeId);

View newVeiw = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("StoreActivity", storeIntent).getDecorView();
setContentView(newVeiw);

Log.e("DEBUG", "current activity: " + getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity().toString());
```

In the StoreActivity layout I have a button which defines an onClick method. For some reason however, it is trying to call this in the parent class that launched StoreActivity. Am I doing something wrong when launching the activity? The output of Log.e above says that StoreActivity is the current activity so I am a bit lost as to why this is happening. I can get around this by defining an onClickListener for the button in code in StoreActvity but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: What code u have in storeActivity class

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are calling setContentView from the parent activity instead of the subactivity. Why don't you just start the activity in the intent instead and set the content view in the new activity? It would be much simpler.

Try this:

```
Intent storeIntent = new Intent(this, StoreActivity.class);
storeIntent.putExtra(StoreActivity.INTENT_STORE_ID, storeId);
startActivity(storeIntent);
```

and then in StoreActivity.java do:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   View newVeiw = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("StoreActivity", storeIntent).getDecorView();

    setContentView(newView); //not sure if this would work, would probably be easier to put your xml layout file in here.
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that this is happening within a single tabbed layout. Unfortunately I cant start the activity using startActivity as it needs to remain a member of the ActivityGroup so that it loads within the same tab as the parent. If I call that it replaces the entire screen with the new activity.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have solved this. The problem was unrelated to any of this code. I had a common base class to my activities and in that I had accidentally made the inflater a singleton. This meant that all inflated layouts belonged to the first class that created that singleton instance which happened to be the class that was incorrectly receiving the onClick event. Removing that singleton resolved this.